# I can not move/scale/rotate my object, instead a coordinate system from the object moves/scales/rotates

Tags: transforms, coordinates

I am very new to Blender, but am already stuck at a point. When moving an object, it does not move the object, but a coordinate system from the object. The same goes for rotating and scaling. I could not find anything about this coordinate system or this problem.
Photos are included.
Thanks in advance!

[image: The object, the cube.]

[image: Tried to move the cube.]

[image: Tried to rotate the cube.]

[image: Tried to scale the cube.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck this tool preference in the properties panel.

[image]